# Why the below code is not giving the correct value in C++11?

Tags: c++

I wrote

```
long long d = 60000000000000001;
cout << (long long ) pow(d,1);
```

but it is showing "60000000000000000" instead of "60000000000000001".

Although if I typecast d with (long double), it is giving correct value. Shouldn't it call (long double)  version itself.

Comment: Floating-point numbers are not exact in many cases, including this one.

Comment: The argument to [`pow`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) is not a `long long`, it's a `float` or `double`. Neither have that much accuracy.

Comment: I mentioned in the details, I am getting "60000000000000000"

Comment: Have you tried `60000000000000001LL` (note the `LL` at the end)?

Comment: @FredOverflow, As the title says C++11 (and `long long` is in use I guess), it will be okay without. The type of an integer literal will now be "upped" if it doesn't fit.

Comment: @Jongware in c++11 we have "long double pow (long double base, long double exponent);" this.

Comment: @VimalRajSharma In some compilers, `long double` has the same precision as `double`.

Comment: @FredOverflow On some architectures, or with some compilers.  It should have more precision than a `double` on an Intel, for example, unless the compiler artificially constrains it.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? Sure, floating point is **imprecise**, but read the entire question: why is it **inconsistent** ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm just going to quote from cppreference.com, and hope that it's accurate with regards to the standard.

In C++11, we have a number of possible overloads, but this is the one that your code uses:

```
Promoted pow( Arithmetic1 base, Arithmetic2 exp );
```

Now, the rules guiding this overload is that if `Arthmetic1` is an integral type (which is what you have), then it's converted to a `double`, not to a `long double`.

So it sounds like you need an explicit cast in your call to `pow()`.

Comment: Thanks. Why so many minuses btw? Is there anything wrong with question or formatting?

Comment: @VimalRajSharma: It's a poorly stated question. Your most recent edit does a lot to help make it better written. Additionally, the initial reaction is that it's just a floating point inaccuracy (which is partially true), which (I think) people are tired of. By extending your answer to say that you thought that it should have used the `long double` version, that makes the question more interesting.

Answer (score 0):

the reason why you get `60000000000000000` instead of the expected `60000000000000001` is the declaration of the pow-method

```
float       pow( float base, float exp );   
double      pow( double base, double exp );
long double pow( long double base, long double exp );
Promoted pow( Arithmetic1 base, Arithmetic2 exp );
```

[source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow)(thx @smarth)

your `long long` is implicitly cast to some floating point datatype and therefore looses the 1

Answer (score 0):

Double-precision floating point values have 15-17 significant decimal digits. When 60000000000000001 (17 decimal digits) is coerced to `double`, it is unable to retain the 16th and 17th decimal digits, so the result is 6.0e16 (or 60000000000000000). When that `double` value is cast back to `long long`, the result is as expected: 60000000000000000. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: I think an edit to the question got posted while I was typing. I missed what apparently was the REAL question, which was related to `long double`.